# SQL Query to Find IDs which are allocated to all available Room_Nos

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very simple problem to find **IDs** in SQL which are allocated to all available **Room_No**. For Example: In following table there are total three unique rooms i.e. **100,400** and **600** and there is only one ID i.e. **1** which is allocated to all available rooms. And I am not able to find a correct query to do this. Please Help

Table Data

```
Room_No   Id
400       1
100       2
600       3
100       1
400       1
600       1
```

Comment: HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT room_no) = 3

Comment: Number of rooms can be more than 3. I just need query to find all IDs which are allocated to all available rooms present in that table.

Comment: Sorry I am newbie in SQL so couldn't understand ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can do this with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select id
from data
group by id
having count(distinct room_no) = (select count(distinct room_no) from data);
```

Comment: I never thought it'd be so much complicated but finally it worked Thanks :)